# Версия файла в InnoSetup

Tags: inno-setup

Добрый день!
Подскажите пожалуйста, как в скрипте InnoSetup указать версию файла для создаваемого инсталлятора?
Версию продукта указываю так:
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}

А версия файла в скомпилированном файле остаётся пустой:

[image: версия файла]

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
```

используйте

```
#define MyAppVersion GetFileVersion('Ваша_аппликация.exe')
VersionInfoVersion={#MyAppVersion}
```